# select, .change() is not triggered in jquery after using .selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason change event is not triggered after I use.selectmenu in jquery 3.1.1. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ewkysvh/1/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("select").selectmenu({width:"13em"});
    $('select').change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
</script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: Did you even search for it? "selectmenu change"

Comment: There's no such thing as `selectmenu`, unless you're using jQuery UI, at which point the documentation clearly states how to capture events.

Comment: Here -> **https://jsfiddle.net/9ewkysvh/2/**

Comment: selectmenu library isnt included. Comment it and it's going to work.

Comment: @adeneo Thanks. I'm new to jQuery.